# How to stop click events from queuing up on multiple click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dhtml

What I need to achieve is if we click on submit button, there is particular div should show up.
Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/7tn5d/
But if I click on submit button multiple times, the function calls sort of queue up and run one after other.
Is there a way to invalidate other onclicks when current animation is running?
Code:

```
 animating = 0;
    doneanim = 0;
    $(function () {
        $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
            if (animating == 1) return;
            animating = 1;
            $("#submit_cont").show("blind", {}, 1000);
            animating = 0;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right with the semaphore! It's just that, in jQuery's `show()`, you would have to put the semaphore reset as an argument. Here's the fixed version - http://jsfiddle.net/snikrs/xe5A3/

```
animating = 0;
doneanim = 0;
$(function () {
    $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
        if (animating == 1) return;
        animating = 1;
        $("#submit_cont").show("blind", 1000, function() {
            animating = 0;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.
Its working now.
But could you explain how its working just be passing animating = 0 in argument when calling "show" function.

Comment: I also found another solution by checking the style property of the div as starting line of function.
If its already set to "display", then just return.
if (document.getElementById("submit_cont").style.display != "none") return;

Comment: Passing `animating = 0` in the argument of the `show()` function satisfies the "Complete" function as described in the jQuery API [here](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: does it means animating will be set to 0 when show function execution completes?

Comment: Yes. When passed as an argument, jQuery will only execute the code in the argument AFTER the animation for `show()` has been completed. In your original code, the `show()` statement is executed, and `animating = 0` is executed immediately after, even before the animation for `show()` is completed.

Comment: So in that case when 2nd time function is called, then animating should be 0 and condition inside if will be false and function must continue further after "if".

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/ssfex/2/
The functions runs when you click it 2nd time but it dosen't animates.
It must animate as if we go according to logic. Its not what I want with my original code but I am not able to understand this behaviour

Comment: Apologies, was careless to not notice that you were using jQuery UI. For jQuery UI, the API for `show()` is `.show( effect [, options ] [, duration ] [, complete ] )`. The order of arguments were wrong. I've updated them in the latest fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/snikrs/xe5A3/. Hope this helps. If you're still experiencing problems with this, let's move this discussion to a chat, to avoid it being spammy. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To prevent it from performing the action multiple times, simple cease the previous animation. So:

```
$('#submit_cont').stop().show("blind",{},1000);
```

However, I have noticed that you have attempted to prevent the animation from running, if an animation is already running. Although it takes 1 second or 1000 milliseconds to show the div, the execution of the condition does not pause until the animation is complete. You must define a function to run after the animation is complete, like so:

```
animating = 0;
doneanim = 0;
$(function () {
    $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
        if (animating == 1) return;
        animating = 1;
        $("#submit_cont").show("blind", 1000, function() { animation = 0; });
    });
});
```

Hope that helped...

Comment: I don't want to cease prev but stop the new ones.

Comment: Ok, then the second option would be best. Simply alter your original code to run a function after the animation is complete, and reset the "animation" variable to 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:animated`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector to check:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
        var $cont = $("#submit_cont");
        if (!$cont.is(':animated')) {
           $cont.show("blind", {}, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Now if you stick with the external semaphore idea then its better to stick that on the elemnt with `.data()` instead of using a global variable:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
        var $cont = $('#submit_cont'),
            animating = $cont.data('isAnimating');
        if (animating) {
           return;
        } else {
          $cont.data('isAnimating', 1);
          $("#submit_cont").show("blind", 1000, function() { $cont.data('isAnimating', 0); });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ([see documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/)) :)

```
$("#submit_cont").show("blind", function(){
    animating = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `$("#submit_cont").clearQueue();` after the animation finished :

```
 $("#submit_tab").click(function (e) {
     $("#submit_cont").show("blind", 1000, function() {
         $("#submit_cont").clearQueue();
     });
 });
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tn5d/4/)

Comment: Its not working. Anyway thanks for help.
I found another solution meanwhile

Comment: I've updated your JSFiddle. It seems to work as you expected or as I understood what you've expected :) . Share your solution so that the answer can help other people with the same problem.

Comment: Yes its working now.
I was applying  $("#submit_cont").clearQueue(); after show function completes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution for this, which in my opinion looks cleaner:

```
var tab = $("submit_tag");
tab.on("click", function(){
    var cont = $("submit_cont");
    var animating = tab.queue("fx").length;
    if(animating === 0){
        cont.show("blind", {}, 1000);
    }
});
```